# How can i route this id.mydomain.com to contoler/action in mvc5 c# app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, routes, action

When site address is like `text.mydomain.com` i want to send user to `mydomain.com/HomeController/ChoosedAction?id=text` How can route this kind of address.
as example:

> mahbub.domain.com

will send user to

> domain.com/controller/action?id='mahbub'

Thanks In Advance